Improving Raspberry Pi Watchdog?
I am currently trying to resolve an issue I have with watchdog on the Raspberry Pi 4B. I have 10 of them, and this seems to be a problem amongst all of them.
Sometimes it works great, however I have noticed during reboots or initially after start-ups, the system will lock up and just stay in that state for days... this is an issue as I am not located near the raspberry pi and can only remotely access it (remote access is not possible when the system is in this locked state).
I have tried multiple different variations of watchdog (ie using apt package daemon and using the built in system.conf). I have found the best results using the systemd built in support. Below is my current configuration:
RuntimeWatchdogSec=10
RebootWatchdogSec=1min
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s
ShutdownWatchdogSec=1min

For context, the PIs are being used to forward network packets essentially, using a custom wireless USB based NIC (which I have a custom linux module for) and forwarding the traffic to an external router connected via ethernet.
What can I do to catch these lockups?
